# Resolving a conversion warning in a compound assignment

Tags: c, type-conversion, warnings, implicit-conversion

In my code I have a lot of `variable <<= 1;` sentences where `variable` is of type uint16_t. The compiler is spitting a warning saying

> conversion to 'uint16_t' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]

How can I resolve it? I could use a long-form notation like `variable = (uint16_t)(variable << 1)` - but I'd like to keep the short notation.

Comment: Those are the "bitwise left shift assignment" and "addition assignment" operator, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to "assignment" though, so there isn't such a complicated title :)

Comment: Name for all kind of operators like this are "compound assignments".

Comment: Great, thanks. Changed the title.

Comment: Can You tell me which compiler you're using and which flags? - Explanation: It tried to reproduce the warning with gcc, didn't succeed. I might be totally mistaken, but the warning doesn't make much sense to me. After all, 1 doesn't get assigned to 'variable', so conversion to uint16_t doesn't make sense to me. 1 shoudl be converted to whatever type the second argument of shift is  - and I'wd expect int or unsigned int ...

Comment: Taking back my question above: To reproduce, use gcc and -Wconversion.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear in my comments, I strongly recommend finding a way to make your code both compile clean and be plainly readable before you go about turning off warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based upon my reading of the standard, you can not get away from this warning for this reason:

```
uint16_t foo;
foo <<= 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
uint16_t foo;
foo = foo << 1;
```

However, this is caught up in the world of "integer promotion".

The value of the "`foo << 1`" expression has the type of "`foo`", however before the left-shift can be conducted it first must go through "integer promotion;" section **6.3.1.1.2** of the C99 standard specifies: "if an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int."

This makes the non-implicit version of your code (with extra parentheses) as follows:

```
uint16_t foo;
foo = ((int)foo) << 1;
```

Given the warning you are on a system with either 32 or 64 bit ints (or anything bigger than 16, really), you are indeed shoving a bigger value into a smaller one.

One way around this is to be explicit with your casts like so:

```
uint16_t foo;
foo = (uint16_t)(foo << 1);
```

But that means that no, you can not use the shorter bitwise shift assignment operator.

If you really are doing this a bunch, consider making a helper function that makes your code clear and compiles cleanly.

```
void LS(uint16_t &value, int shift) {  // LS means LeftShift
  *value = (uint16_t)(*value << shift);
}

LS(&foo, 1);
```

TL;DR:  No, you can't use the short operator and avoid that warning at the same time.

Comment: I've just now also reading the standard and agree: It says this. But I wonder why this kind of conversion happens for bit wise shift. After all, there is no real realationship between the width of the value shifted and the width of the value required to specify the amount by which is is shifted.

Comment: My understanding is that the whole promotion question (fetch the rationale and read the section on promotion for grittyness) combined with the need to have consistent behavior on architectures that can't do bit-shifting on less-than-word-sized units means the compiler needs to be free to enforce only word-size shifts/rotations.  Toss in a need for consistency and you're stuck with mandating promotion for bit shift operations.  EDIT: Frankly today was the first time I'd ever had reason to read the standard's take on the shift operators. Learn something new every day I guess.

Comment: Are you sure the non-implicit version is `((unsigned int)foo)` ? I tend to think it's actually `int`.

Comment: I'm sure. It's required by the C99 standard.

Comment: @cnicutar is correct, integer promotion makes it `int`, not `unsigned int`. See 6.3.1.1.2 "If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int" (also in C11). Surely an int can represent all values of an uint16_t, in this case. Also, note that GCC complains about a conversion from 'int', not from 'unsigned int'.

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because `variable <<= 1;` is equivalent to:

```
variable = variable << 1;
```

where the right-hand side has type `int`, not `uint16_t`, due to default integer promotions. The best way around this is not to use smaller-than-`int` types.

Comment: What I am doing is actually calculating CRC so I am obliged to use these types. Do you propose I use the long notation to get rid of this warning?

Comment: I am doing other compound assignments too :)

Comment: There's no real reason to use `uint16_t`. `unsigned` works just as well. Just truncate the value using the `&` or `%` operator when needed.